# IGraph/M Documentation issue

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages, igraphm

When consulting the IGRaph/M documentation like this:

```
<< IGraphM`
IGDocumentation[]
```

I get this as an output:

```
Evaluate IGDocumentation[] to get started.
```

then a notebook pops up  but when i click on any function link I get something like this:

```
MapThread::mptd: Object FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$247 at position {2, 1} in MapThread[FrontEnd`Private`settouch,{FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$247,FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$247}] has only 0 of required 1 dimensions. >>
FE`ExecuteInDynamicModule::noval: Symbol FE`DynamicModuleVariableList$247 does not have a value. >>
```

what this message is supposed to mean ?

Comment: I think this is not the right place for this question. Can you open [an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/issues) instead?  Click the green button. I heard complaints about this, but I could never reproduce the problem. I am going to need to ask you many questions to figure out what's wrong and that's not really possible here on SE. But we can have that conversation on GitHub. I would like to fix this problem so I would appreciate any help with reproducing it. If you don't want to do the GitHub thing, we can talk in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48300/igraph-m).

Comment: @ Szabolcs. Sure. I don't have a github account and don't know how to use it but will be more than glad to chat if that can be of any help.

Comment: If anyone else sees this problem, I would appreciate any help in reproducing it.

Comment: The latest version displays the documentation in a different manner.  Perhaps that solves this issue too.

Comment: @Szabolcs. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

While I could never reproduce this, recent versions of IGraph/M use a different method to display the documentation.  Hopefully it is immune to this problem.

Keep in mind that the package must be loaded before the usage links will work.